ValueError: Invalid input shape when combining image, mask, and CSV data in Keras model
I’m working on a deep learning model using Keras where I’m trying to combine three inputs: images, masks, and CSV data. The goal of my model is to predict the presence and type of brain hemorrhage from medical images (CT scans) and CSV data. I have structured the model using an Attention U-Net for image segmentation and a dense layer for CSV data processing.
The input data consists of:

Images: Grayscale CT scans with shape (256, 256, 1).

Masks: Binary masks corresponding to the segmentation with shape (256, 256, 1).

CSV Data: Numerical data for various hemorrhage types with shape (6,).


I’m encountering the following error when trying to train the model using model.fit():
ValueError: Invalid input shape for input Tensor("functional_1/Cast:0", shape=(None, 6), dtype=float32). Expected shape (None, 256, 256, 1), but input has incompatible shape (None, 6)
It seems that the CSV data, which has a shape of (None, 6), is being fed into the model where the image data (with shape (None, 256, 256, 1)) is expected. I’ve double-checked the input shapes and used train_test_split to split the data, but the issue persists.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
# Model definition
inputs, outputs = attention_unet()  # UNet model for images

csv_input = layers.Input(shape=(6,), name='csv_input')  # CSV data input

mask_input = layers.Input(shape=(256, 256, 1), name='mask_input')  # Mask input

# CSV data processing
csv_x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(csv_input)csv_x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(csv_x)

# Combine CSV with U-Net output
flatten_outputs = layers.Flatten()(outputs)combined = layers.Concatenate()([flatten_outputs, csv_x])

# Final output
final_output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='final_output')(combined)

# Model compilation
model = models.Model(inputs=[inputs, csv_input, mask_input], outputs=[outputs, final_output])model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss={'final_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'outputs': 'categorical_crossentropy'}, metrics=['accuracy', dice_coef, jaccard_index])

# Data shapes
print(f"Shape of X_train: {X_train.shape}")  # Shape of images: (batch_size, 256, 256, 1)print(f"Shape of csv_train: {csv_train.shape}")  # Shape of CSV: (batch_size, 6)print(f"Shape of y_train: {y_train.shape}")  # Shape of masks: (batch_size, 256, 256, 1)

# Model training
model.fit({'input_layer': X_train, 'csv_input': csv_train, 'mask_input': y_train},{'final_output': csv_train, 'outputs': y_train},validation_data=({'input_layer': X_val, 'csv_input': csv_val, 'mask_input': y_val},{'final_output': csv_val, 'outputs': y_val}),epochs=50,batch_size=32,callbacks=callbacks)

Steps I’ve Tried:

I’ve printed the shapes of the training data, and they all seem correct:

Images: (batch_size, 256, 256, 1)
CSV: (batch_size, 6)
Masks: (batch_size, 256, 256, 1)


I’ve checked the order of data input in model.fit() to ensure the data is being passed to the correct layers.

How can I resolve this shape mismatch issue and correctly combine the image, mask, and CSV data in the model?

Please show more of your code. The part where you pass the mask_input layer to the u-net is missing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

this happens when you try to combine image data (shape: (None, 256, 256, 1)) with CSV data (shape: (None, 6)). The issue arises because the CSV data and image data are being mixed incorrectly in the model.
this code should work for you:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.losses import binary_crossentropy, categorical_crossentropy

# Assuming `attention_unet` is your function that returns the U-Net model
def attention_unet():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(256, 256, 1), name='image_input')  # Input for images
    # Build your U-Net architecture here
    # outputs = ... (this would be your segmentation output)
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(inputs)  # Example output
    return inputs, outputs

# Model definition
image_input, segmentation_output = attention_unet()  # UNet model for images

# CSV data input
csv_input = layers.Input(shape=(6,), name='csv_input')

# Mask input for segmentation task
mask_input = layers.Input(shape=(256, 256, 1), name='mask_input')

# CSV data processing
csv_x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(csv_input)
csv_x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(csv_x)

# Flatten the U-Net's segmentation output to combine with CSV data
flatten_segmentation_output = layers.Flatten()(segmentation_output)

# Combine flattened segmentation output with CSV processed data
combined = layers.Concatenate()([flatten_segmentation_output, csv_x])

# Classification output (predicting hemorrhage type)
classification_output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='final_output')(combined)

# Define the model with inputs and outputs
model = models.Model(inputs=[image_input, csv_input, mask_input],
                     outputs=[segmentation_output, classification_output])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),
              loss={'final_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'conv2d': 'categorical_crossentropy'},  # replace 'conv2d' with the correct name of the segmentation output
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Print model summary to verify the architecture
model.summary()

# Example data shapes (for illustration purposes):
X_train = np.random.rand(32, 256, 256, 1)  # Images
csv_train = np.random.rand(32, 6)  # CSV Data
y_train = np.random.rand(32, 256, 256, 1)  # Masks

X_val = np.random.rand(32, 256, 256, 1)  # Validation images
csv_val = np.random.rand(32, 6)  # Validation CSV data
y_val = np.random.rand(32, 256, 256, 1)  # Validation masks

# Training the model
model.fit({'image_input': X_train, 'csv_input': csv_train, 'mask_input': y_train},
          {'final_output': csv_train, 'conv2d': y_train},  # 'conv2d' needs to match the segmentation output's layer name
          validation_data=({'image_input': X_val, 'csv_input': csv_val, 'mask_input': y_val},
                           {'final_output': csv_val, 'conv2d': y_val}),
          epochs=50, batch_size=32)

